# Mover cambios de master a otra rama y regresar master a commit anterior

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Tengo mi History

A->B->C->D->E->F->MASTER

Quiero regresar a master al commit C y deshacer los cambios pero mantener los cambios en otra rama, Ejemplo:

A->B->C->MASTER

D->E->F->NUEVO BRANCH

Comment: Crea el nuevo branch, regresa a master, y revierte los commits.

Comment: Dependiendo de la situación, es preferible regresar rama a la revisión anterior en vez de hacer reversiones. En todo caso, si la persona es principiante, es mejor hacerle la receta en una respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

```
git branch nueva-rama master
git checkout master
git reset --hard C
```

Espero que no tengas cambios no acometidos al hacer el reset porque se van a perder.

Esa es la receta para ramas locales. Si te funciona bien y entonces quieres mover también  ramas **remotas**, crea otra pregunta.